# TwitPic image upload 

Tags: php, image, upload, twitpic

I want to implement [TwitPic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TwitPic) image uploads (in PHP) using [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).
In that the flow is like

1. login amd allow or deny (application)
2. then return image upload

That image upload is used for all the users.
Is there any code or link to help full to me?
Is there any link to guide me?

Comment: do the work for you huh?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the documentation [here](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/).

If you are not comfortable with using their API then you could use one of the following libraries.

**PHP**

[TwitPic API for PHP](http://github.com/meltingice/TwitPic-API-for-PHP) - created by [@meltingice](http://twitter.com/meltingice)
[Services_TwitPic](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_TwitPic) - created by Bill Shupp

**Javascript**
[TwitPic API for JavaScript](http://github.com/meltingice/TwitPic-API-for-Javascript) - by [@meltingice](http://twitter.com/meltingice)

And you need to register for an [API Key](http://dev.twitpic.com/apps/new) for making request.

Comment: ya have do this thing but not helpfull to me.

Comment: @user441423 You have not mentioned what you have tried in your question. Can I know what problem you are facing while implementing this library ?